# Using jquery $.each with multiple selectors

Tags: jquery

I want get all the accesskeys that are on a button or link. I have the following.

```
$(":button[accesskey!=''], :a[accesskey!='']").each(function(i) {
 //code
});
```

You can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/QNPZU/

I thought you could have multiple selectors by separating them using a comma but the above code does not work.

If I do

```
$(":*[accesskey!='']").each(function(i) {
 //code
});
```

it will work, but I take it there will be a performance problem if the dom is huge?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can code:

```
$("button[accesskey], a[accesskey]").each(function(i) {
   //code
});
```

Comment: Are you sure :button is deprecated. It seems to be in the main api

Comment: @Karsten `:button` and `:radio` and several other selectors were deprecated  as of jQuery 1.7 and jQuery developers suddenly removed the deprecation notice. Now I have several answers that say "the x selector is deprecated" which is not true anymore. One of them is this answer. Good call. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use `a` instead of `:a`:

```
$(":button[accesskey!=''], a[accesskey!='']").each(function(i) {
 //code
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/QNPZU/3/

Answer (score 0):

Check this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/QNPZU/2/

There were 2 problems with your code.

a. For selecting links and buttons, you need to use `a` and `button` and not `:a` and `:button`

b. You can select items with an attribute called accesskey simply by using `a[accesskey]`. you need not use `a[accesskey!=""]`

Comment: Thanks the answer. What does the colon do different?

Comment: The ':XYZ' notation is for filtering using runtime properties like :visible, :checked etc.. For selecting all elements of a given tag, simply use the tag name as specified in the API doc (previous comment)